# Transmitting data over FTDI usb-RS485

Tags: serial, ftdi

I am trying to using a USB-RS485 cable (which utilizes the FT323R). I have it configured to be all output, and to run in async bit bang mode.

I am only able to see data on my scope if I call the set Break on and set Break off right before each FT_Write Command. If I don't call those set Break On and Set Break Off, I can't see a differential on the wire.

Is there a reason for this? This seems wrong, am I configuring something wrong?

EDIT: Added Code!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ftd2xx.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "string.h"
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   uint32_t numDevs;
    FT_HANDLE FT_handle;
    FT_STATUS FT_status;    // status of the FT 232 chip
    
    //Open Device
    FT_STATUS ftStatus;      
    char * value = "FT4T6TXN";
    ftStatus = FT_OpenEx(value,FT_OPEN_BY_SERIAL_NUMBER, &FT_handle);

    if(ftStatus == FT_OK){
        printf("successful open!\n");
    }else{
        printf("failure open! %d\n", ftStatus);
    }

    UCHAR Mask = 0xFF; //all output
    UCHAR Mode = 0x01; //Selects the Async Bit Bang Mode

    ftStatus = FT_SetBitMode(FT_handle,Mask,Mode);
    if (ftStatus == FT_OK) {
        // synchronous Bit bang Mode enabled  
        printf("sync bit mode!\n");
    }
    else {
        // FT_SetBitMode FAILED!
        printf("setBitModeFailed!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    
    DWORD BaudRate;
    BaudRate = 366;
    FT_status  = FT_SetBaudRate(FT_handle,BaudRate);
    if(FT_status != FT_OK){
        printf("BAUD RATE SET FAILED! \n");
        return -1;
    }

    uint32_t bytesWritten = 0;    
    UCHAR Buffer = 0x01;    // data to be written to the port
    
    //set flow control
    FT_status = FT_SetFlowControl(FT_handle, FT_FLOW_RTS_CTS, NULL, NULL);
    if(FT_status != FT_OK){
        printf("flow not okay\n");
    }

    //Begin Looping Inf
    while(true){
        //I was unable to see Data without calling this?

        FT_SetBreakOn(FT_handle);
        FT_SetBreakOff(FT_handle);

        //WRITE
        FT_status = FT_Write( FT_handle,      // handle to the chip
                        &Buffer,        // address of the data
                        sizeof(Buffer), // Size of the Buffer
                        &BytesWritten   // Number of bytes written 
                    );

        sleep(1);
  
     if(FT_status != FT_OK){
         printf("write not successful! %d \n", FT_status);
     }

    }
   FT_Close(FT_handle); // Close the Serial port connection   
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of bit bang mode? Why not simply send UART data normally?

Comment: @Justme I'm trying to emulate another device which runs in a pretty custom setting. I believe if I tried to send it UART it would add start/parity bits that I can't have. The reason I went for BitBang is because I just want the raw data... if I only want to send 1010, only send 1010 on that connection.

Comment: Well what are you sending? Where's the code to review? What baud rate? Is it 232RQ or 232RL as there is a difference?

Comment: My apologies! Just added the coded.. I set the baud rate to one of the slowest it uses (366). This is using FT232RQ

Comment: But you are sending constant bit pattern, you are not changing any pin if you don't change the data.

Comment: from my understanding.. if theres only 1 pin (I thought it was TXD+ and TXD-), wouldn't it clock through? 1010 or so? Am I not understanding how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bit pattern is not sent out one one pin. The bit pattern is set to all 8 bits of the bit bang data bus, where TXD is bit 0.

So you need to send a repeating requence of 0x00,0x01,0x00,0x01,etc to make the bit bang data bus pin 0 go low and high.

Comment: Ah. So if I just dropped that into a while loop I could continuous keep changing my LSB to keepw riting different values? Why was I able to see different data on that bit toggling the break?

Comment: Because setting break on means to pull TXD low and setting break off means pushing TXD high. It is unexpected that break works in bitbang mode, but the break state can internally be implemented via bitbang anyway.

Comment: So I guess where that was my mistake was,, I thought data was being cycled through that buffer .. sounds like that isn't the case

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was able to test it.. you were right... only thing, I was setting my baud rate at 10k, which should mean i have a new value every 100 uS. If I'm commanding in a while loop, would i need a sleep delay to ensure I don't overwrite that value in my write command? my while loop should execute faster than that